# When the slice do shallow copy and when it do deep copy in Python 3

Tags: python, slice, deep-copy, shallow-copy

```
bs = [1, 2, 3]
print(id(bs))
print(id(bs[:]))
xs = bs[:]
xs[1] = [9, 9, 9]
print(bs)
print(xs)
-------------
4452573000
4452573064
[1, 2, 3]
[1, [9, 9, 9], 3]
```

It seems that the `bs[:]` do a deep copy to `xs`

```
bs = [1, 2, 3]
print(id(bs))
print(id(bs[:])) 
xs = bs[:] = [4, 5, 6]
print(id(xs))
print(bs)
print(xs)
----------
4518600520
4518600584
4518600584
[4, 5, 6]
[4, 5, 6]
```

It seems that the `bs[:]` do a shallow copy to `xs`

The `bs[:] = [4, 5, 6]` will modify the original list of `bs` to `[4, 5, 6]`.
But if just do `xs = bs[:]` and `xs[1] = [9, 9, 9]`, it won't affect the the original list of bs which is still `[1,2,3]`

Comment: ID values are only guaranteed to be distinct for objects with overlapping lifetimes. `id` is almost useless for new learners of Python, because extracting any useful meaning from the results requires a deceptively high level of understanding.

Comment: List slices *always create shallow copies*. What makes you think "It seems that the bs[:] do a deep copy to xs"???

Answer (score 4):

For lists, and for most sequence types, slice retrieval makes a shallow copy of the sliced section of the list. In `xs = bs[:]`, `xs` becomes a copy of `bs`

Slice *assignment*, on the other hand, does not make a copy of the sliced section. In `bs[:] = [4, 5, 6]`, no copy is made of any part of `bs`. The contents of `[4, 5, 6]` are assigned directly into `bs`. (These contents are references to int objects, and the references are what are copied - we don't mutate any ints.)

---

In the chained assignment `xs = bs[:] = [4, 5, 6]`, the value assigned to `xs` is the list produced by the `[4, 5, 6]` expression on the right, not a slice of `bs`. The assignment is executed as

```
temp = [4, 5, 6]
xs = temp
bs[:] = temp
```

not as

```
bs[:] = [4, 5, 6]
xs = bs[:]
```

No slice retrieval is performed, and no copies of `bs` are made.

---

I am not aware of a single type in the Python language core, the Python standard library, or any commonly used third-party library where slicing performs a deep copy. Some types, like memoryviews and NumPy arrays, return a *view* of the original object's data for slice retrieval, but that's even less of a copy than a shallow copy.

Answer (score 1):

Assigning from a slice of a list always shallow copies - that is, it copies the references in the source list.

When you assign to a list (whether it was created by copying or any other method), you're not mutating the object referenced - you're changing the reference in the list so now it points at something else. That's what's going on in your first example here:

```
xs[1] = [9, 9, 9]
```

That changes `xs[1]` to a reference to your new list of `[9, 9, 9`]. It doesn't matter what the source of `xs`'s contents was.

Where this can matter is if you have a list of mutable objects, and if you use mutation methods on them rather than reassigning:

```
bs = [[1], [2], [3]]
xs = bs[:] # now xs is a shallow copy of bs - it contains references to the same objects
xs[1].append(4)
```

Here, `xs[1]` is a reference to the same list as `bs[1]`, so the mutation call would affect it regardless of which reference you use to get it.